# I am trying to make my code work for singular inputs eg: when i input 1 it should return 0 hours , 1 minute instead of 0 hours, 1 minutes

Tags: javascript

The code runs pretty well with plural numbers. eg: 150 output: 2 hours, 30 minutes, but when i add a singular either in hours or minutes it still outputs: hours and minutes instead of hour and minute.

```
function timeConverter(number) {
  var num = number

  var hours = (num / 60);

  var hrs = Math.floor(hours);
  var minutes = (hours - hrs) * 60;
  var min = Math.round(minutes);
  return +hrs + " hours, " + min + " minutes."
}

console.log(timeConverter(1)
```

Comment: What does not work? Add more details

Comment: What's a plural number?

Comment: may be 1 minute, 2 minutes

Comment: i am trying to make my code work for singular inputs eg: when i input 1 it should return  0 hours , 1 minute instead of 1 minutes.

Comment: simple condition check won't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ternary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator for this.

```js
function timeConverter(number) {
  var num = number

  var hours = (num / 60);

  var hrs = Math.floor(hours);
  var minutes = (hours - hrs) * 60;
  var min = Math.round(minutes);
  return +hrs + (hrs==1 ? " hour, " : " hours, ") + min + (min==1 ? " minute." : " minutes.")
}

console.log(timeConverter(1));
console.log(timeConverter(60));
```

Comment: @NATHANIEL Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

Modern way with a template literal and a function

also removed a lot of cruft in your code, because this is really simple

```js
function timeConverter(number) {
  
  const min = number % 60;
  const hrs = (number - min) / 60;
  
  const plural = v => v === 1 ? '' : 's';
  
  return `${hrs} hour${plural(hrs)}, ${min} minute${plural(min)}.`;
}

console.log(timeConverter(1));
console.log(timeConverter(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the simplest way

```js
function timeConverter(number) {
  var num = number

  var hours = (num / 60);

  var hrs = Math.floor(hours);
  var minutes = (hours - hrs) * 60;
  var min = Math.round(minutes);
  var hrsUnit = hrs > 1? " hours, " : " hour, ";
  var minsUnit = min > 1 ? " minutes." : " minute.";
  
  return hrs + hrsUnit + min + minsUnit;
}

console.log(timeConverter(10));
```